# Fedora, Gnome 3 and nVidia Optimus: Mouse leaves trails

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, mouse, fedora

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 7559, with a discrete nVidia Geforce 960M graphics card. I don't use wayland, but X.Org, and Gnome 3.

After installing nvidia propertiary drivers in Fedora 27, everything seems to be working fine aside from a couple of things:

- Mouse seems to be "ghosting", leaving a small trail when you move it (similar to the old "mouse trail" effect from Windows 98)
- When switching tabs in chrome, mouse seems to be leaving a noticeable bigger trail for a split second (the tab also takes that split second more to switch, compared to nouveau)
- Sometimes the display "freezes" for a split second, without leaving any trail in the logs about why

I used this tutorial to install Nvidia drivers: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA - so it's basically installing two packages from RPMFusion.

I also tried negativo17 repository (https://github.com/negativo17/nvidia-driver), but that also didn't help.

In general, nouveau works "fine", but not "great". I decided to give nvidia drivers a shot, and I noticed that most of the time, the desktop environment feels a lot smoother (like going from a 24fps video to a 60fps one).

Some additional info:

- My BIOS doesn't allow me to select "hybrid" vs "discrete only" graphics card mode
- I tried playing with "TearFree" options in X.org, but without any luck - perhaps I might be doing something wrong here, because my X.org only uses automatic configuration, I apply all changes using the `xorg.conf.d` directory
- The driver version that gets installed through `akmods` is `390.25`

Obviously, it's not going to be as easy as 'install the drivers and forget', but perhaps somebody know what other might I try to get nvidia drivers to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although I use Arch Linux. The way I fixed it was to first disable and then re-enable PRIME Synchronization using xrandr:

To disable:

```
xrandr --output <output> --set "PRIME Synchronization" 0
```

And then to enable:

```
xrandr --output <output> --set "PRIME Synchronization" 1
```

Where  is the name of my display. In my case, it's eDP-1-1 - you can find this out by looking at the output of `xrandr --verbose`

Comment: Thank you for that. I actually managed to find this out through experimenting and various old posts I've been able to find. Although it does help, it's not really a solution.

I've made a script that triggers this for all displays upon login, which is an acceptable workaround for now, although not perfect.